# connecting via ssh using pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have three ec2 instances (ec2-01, ec2-02 and ec2-03) with ubuntu installed. I have pem-key-1 associated with ec2-01 and ec2-02 and pem-key-2 associated with ec2-03.

I have setup passwordless ssh between ec2-01 and ec2-02 using below commands and it's working.

```
ssh-keygen (generates key)
ssh-copy-id user@ec2-02 (copies ssh key to remote ec2)
ssh user@ec2-02 (login to remote ec2)
```

Next, I want to setup passwordless ssh from ec2-01/ec2-02 to ec2-03. I think I have to use ssh-keygen with pem_key_2 but don't know the correct way to do this. FYI, I am able to login to ec2-03 using below command from ec2-01:

`ssh -i pem-key-2 user@ec2-03`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh-copy-id` copies the *public* side of the keypair that `ssh-keygen` generates and drops it on `ec2-02` so that the *private* side of the keypair (`pem-key-2` based on your ssh command) is sufficient to authorize your connection ( this is done by adding the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote end, but `ssh-copy-id` took care of that detail for you).

to be able to login to `ec2-03` from `ec2-02` you'd have to either copy the private key from `ec2-01` to `ec2-03` or else just repeat the steps to generate a key pair on ec2-02 and distribute to ec2-03 the same way you did between ec2-01 and ec2-02.  All else being equal I'd recommend the later option; ideally, private keys of any kind are not transmitted over the network if it can be avoided, even a secure connection, and it's a best practice the industry still struggles with today.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Farrell